# How to check which line of a bash script is being executed

Tags: bash, shell-script, monitoring

Is there a way to check which line *number* of a `bash` script is being executed "right now"?

Using `bash -x script.sh` looks promising; however, I need to get the current line number.

Answer (score 21):

Combine [`xtrace`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355965/how-to-check-which-line-of-the-bash-script-is-being-executed/355968#comment630794_355965) with [`PS4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10815288/96588) inside the script:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
PS4='+${LINENO}: '

sleep 1m
sleep 1d
$ timeout 5 ./test.sh
+3: PS4='+${LINENO}: '
+5: sleep 1m
```

or [in the parent shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355965/how-to-check-which-line-of-a-bash-script-is-being-executed/355968?noredirect=1#comment631087_355968):

```
$ cat test.sh 
sleep 1m
sleep 1d
$ export PS4='+${LINENO}: '
$ timeout 5 bash -x ./test.sh
+1: sleep 1m
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is a way.
There is an array of line numbers where a function has been called.

Define this function:

```
f(){ echo "${BASH_LINENO[-2]}"; }
```

And call `f` at any line that you want the line number, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash


f(){ echo "${BASH_LINENO[-2]}"; }

f

echo next1
f

echo next2
f

echo next 3
f
```

Will print:

```
6
next 1
9
next 2
12
next 3
15
```

It could be expanded to show the trail of functions called:

```
#!/bin/bash

f(){
    for ((i=${#BASH_LINENO[@]}-1;i>=0;i--)); do
    printf '<%s:%s> ' "${FUNCNAME[i]}" "${BASH_LINENO[i]}";
    done
    echo "$LINENO"
 }

SomeOtherFunction(){ echo -n "test the line numbering:  "; f; }

f

echo next 1
echo -n "    This line numbering:  "; f
SomeOtherFunction

echo next 2
echo -n "    This line numbering:  "; f
SomeOtherFunction

echo next 3
echo -n "    This line numbering:  "; f
```

Which will print:

```
$ ./script
<main:0> <f:12> 7
next 1
    This line numbering:  <main:0> <f:15> 7
test the line numbering:  <main:0> <SomeOtherFunction:16> <f:10> 7
next 2
    This line numbering:  <main:0> <f:19> 7
test the line numbering:  <main:0> <SomeOtherFunction:20> <f:10> 7
next 3
    This line numbering:  <main:0> <f:23> 7
```

Note that above the `echo "$LINENO"` output is always the same (7 in this case).

Answer (score 7):

Here’s a solution
that borrows parts of [l0b0’s](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/355965/80216#355968) and [DopeGhoti’s](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/355965/80216#355971) answers
(and, to a lesser extent, [sorontar’s](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/355965/80216#356013)). 
Like those answers, mine uses `$LINENO` to discover the line number;
unlike them, I use `trap` to trigger the reporting. 
bash’s `trap` command is described in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> `trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]`
>
>   The command
>   *arg*
>   is to be read and executed
>     when the shell receives signal(s)
>   *sigspec*
>   .  … ⁠
>         ︙
>   …  If a
>   *sigspec*
>   is
>   **DEBUG**
>   ,
>     the command
>   *arg*
>   is executed before every
>   *simple command*
>   ,
>   `for`
>   command,
>   `case`
>   command,
>   `select`
>   command,
>     every arithmetic
>   `for`
>   command,
>     and before the first command executes in a shell function …

So this script:

```
$ cat -n myscript
     1  #!/bin/bash
     2  trap 'printf "%3d: " "$LINENO"' DEBUG
     3  date
     4  sleep 30
     5  date
     6  sleep \
     7        11
     8  date
     9
    10  ls -l
    11  for f in *
    12  do
    13          echo "$f"  &&
    14                         ls -ld "$f"
    15  done
    16
    17  for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
    18  do
    19          echo "i = $i"; date
    20  done
    21
    22  echo $((5+25+12))
$
```

runs the `printf "%3d: " "$LINENO"` command
before every command in the script, and produces this output:

```
$ ./myscript
  3: Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:16:17 AM
  4:   5: Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:16:47 AM
  7:   8: Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:16:58 AM
 10: total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 221 Apr  5 10:01 myscript
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 252 Apr  5 10:01 myscript2
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup 132 Apr  5 09:59 myscript2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup  45 Apr  5 08:34 other_file
 11:  13: myscript
 14: -rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 221 Apr  5 10:01 myscript
 11:  13: myscript2
 14: -rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 252 Apr  5 10:01 myscript2
 11:  13: myscript2.log
 14: -rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup 132 Apr  5 09:59 myscript2.log
 11:  13: other_file
 14: -rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup  45 Apr  5 08:34 other_file
 17:  17:  19: i = 0
 19: Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:16:59 AM
 17:  17:  19: i = 1
 19: Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:16:59 AM
 17:  17:  19: i = 2
 19: Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:16:59 AM
 17:  17:  22: 42
$
```

Notes:

- Like [l0b0’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/355965/80216#355968), this is minimally invasive — just add line 2.
- Unlike [l0b0’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/355965/80216#355968),
  this doesn’t display the commands themselves —
  but you didn’t ask for it to do that.
- The second `sleep`, which spans script lines 6 and 7,
  is reported as line 7.
- Line 11 (`for f in *`) is reported once
  before each iteration of that `for` loop.
- `echo "$f"` and `ls -ld "$f"` are correctly reported
  on their respective lines (13 and 14).
- Line 17 (`for ((i=0; i<3; i++))`) is reported ***twice***
  before each iteration of that `for` loop,
  and twice more after the last iteration.
- Unlike `set -x`, `LINENO` and `PS4`
  (which are specified by the POSIX standard),
  the DEBUG `trap` is a bash extension and will not work in all shells.
- The DEBUG `trap` can run any command(s),
  and is not restricted to writing to the script’s standard output
  or standard error.

The question says, «check which line number of a bash script
is being executed “right now”» without specifying a user interface. 
Another approach is to continually write the current line number
to a log file:

```
$ diff myscript myscript2
2c2
< trap 'printf "%3d: " "$LINENO"' DEBUG
---
> exec 6> myscript2.log  &&  trap 'printf "%3d\n" "$LINENO" >&6' DEBUG
$ ./myscript2
Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:23:50 AM
Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:24:20 AM
Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:24:31 AM
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 221 Apr  5 10:01 myscript
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 252 Apr  5 10:01 myscript2
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup  24 Apr  5 10:23 myscript2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup  45 Apr  5 08:34 other_file
myscript
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 221 Apr  5 10:01 myscript
myscript2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroup 252 Apr  5 10:01 myscript2
myscript2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup  60 Apr  5 10:23 myscript2.log
other_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup  45 Apr  5 08:34 other_file
i = 0
Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:24:31 AM
i = 1
Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:24:31 AM
i = 2
Wed, Apr 05, 2017 10:24:31 AM
42
$
```

We can monitor the execution of this script
by monitoring the contents of the `myscript2.log` file
from another terminal. 
For example, during the second `sleep`,

```
$ tail myscript2.log
  3
  4
  5
  7
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `echo $LINENO` in a script and it should output whatever line that command happens to be on.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $LINENO

$ ./foo.sh
2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

Add that "-x" at the start of your script. Then every time you execute the script it will echo the line your script is executing. like an execution tree of your script.

Comment: The OP has already dismissed this suggestion as being unsatisfactory.